# hs.logger set Default log level for new logger instances to INFO instead if Warning

Tags: haskell

I'm using hs.logger and the default behaviour is to display only the WARNING Level by default.I would like to set it to DEBUG or INFO when I'm developping locally... I found this function `hs.logger.defaultLogLevel` on the documentation (http://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.logger.html#defaultLogLevel) but I'm not able to find this function in the Library ! If you think there is a better Library to use in haskell, please say it to me as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with hslogger, but this part from the [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hslogger-1.2.10/docs/System-Log-Logger.html) seems relevant:

```
   -- Now we'd like to see everything from BuggyComponent
   -- at DEBUG or higher go to syslog and stderr.
   -- Also, we'd like to still ignore things less than
   -- WARNING in other areas.
   -- 
   -- So, we adjust the Logger for MyApp.BuggyComponent.

   updateGlobalLogger "MyApp.BuggyComponent"
                      (setLevel DEBUG)

   -- This message will go to syslog and stderr
   debugM "MyApp.BuggyComponent" "This buggy component is buggy"
```

Comment: it works only for a specific instance in this case (for the logger instance "MyApp.BuggyComponent"), but  I wanted to have it for all the instances you could create along the process flow...

Comment: @NicolasHenin What about using `getRootLogger`, then `setLevel`, then `saveGlobalLogger` ? Just guessing here... Or even `updateGlobalLogger rootLoggerName (setLevel INFO)`?